# Are there any other backups (keychain etc.) needed for an iOS developer after migrating from one Mac to another?

Tags: mac, backup, migration

I have migrated my Mac using Apple's migration assistant.

I develop iOS apps and uploading and distributing them from the "new" Mac works well. I am about to wipe and sell the old Mac. Is there anything—especially looking at keychain being locked on a different machine(?)—I should do now?

It probably won't be an issue but I just wanna play it safe.

Comment: FWIW, I removed your complaint about timestamps but there was an easier solution to this: Instead of using the migration assistant, just clone your old systems drive on an external hard drive of some kind using a tool like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) and then booting the new machine off of that copy, and then cloning the backup onto a clean reformat of your new machine. I’ve been doing this for more than a decade on Macs and it works fine. macOS is not tied to hardware the way Windows machines are. If your old machine is still around, I would recommend you do that.

Comment: I'd second @JakeGould 's method. My Macs have 'direct line of sight' back to about 2001 using this type of method [plus in the old days simply swapping the drive into the newer machine]. All 3 of my Macs here are essentially 'offspring' of that one grandaddy Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you've been using Time Machine or some other trustworthy fully-automated periodic backup of your whole system, preferably to at least one local external drive or fileserver/NAS and at least one offsite location. So just do one last local and one last offsite backup, **test your backups**, and then rest easy.

Don't forget to deauthorize your machine from iTunes and sign out of iCloud (especially Find My Mac) before you wipe it. Be sure to use a secure erase when you wipe it.